# Check for object property in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a queryParams object and I want to query the DB with it's properties, But I can't check which params it has.
I tried to use

```
find(queryParameters: object = { limit: 50 }){
if (queryParameters.hasOwnProperty("limit")) {
   console.log( queryParameters.limit)
}
}
```

but it's keep saying that Property 'limit' does not exist on type 'object'. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why is the type annotation `object` instead of something more specific?

Comment: like what? I'm totally beginner to TS, you mean using smth like interfaces?

Comment: Well, for example if you aren't sure whether the object has a `limit` property or not, the type could be `{limit?: number}`. You could declare the type as an interface or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I am gonna assume that u have a query parameter class like the following:

```
class QueryParm {
    // offset is optional
    // limit has the default value = 50
    constructor(public offset?: number, public limit: number = 50) {}
}

function find(queryParameters: QueryParm){ 
    // check if the limit is defined which it should be ( using the default value )
    if (queryParameters.limit) {
        console.log(queryParameters.limit)
    } else {
        console.log("no queryParameters falling back to default ...")
    }
    // check if the offset is defined
    if(queryParameters.offset) {
        console.log(queryParameters.offset)
    } else {
        console.log("offset not found")
    }
}

find(new QueryParm())
// offset = 20
find(new QueryParm(20))
```

I hope this answers your question link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTATgTwApmQW2gbwChpjpgB7AOwgBdl5hqzkAKAB3gCMQBLYaMgGYCIiagH4AXNArxsHFABpo7Lr2g9s3alJlyU0ALzQArAAYAlPgC+BGwQHwKDbpWgDuFACbMAjkjSYyGDYoigQUggoGFjY5njQRCQA9EmkABaIwADW0NwC0NQZ6tya1LkwnojuFIie0ADuabxpuWUQaWTwIHXy0MzQ8BAeAOYFRZUCYF1lAG5gIEjQ5onEeX1+UYHBocgQAHQaWpaEJKeklBBkIIgHZMO+-tFBIdRhByVHK9BW0IggIvgvqdyFQrjcQHdmAAiChkaAbAJYbavXZueY8CijDhgbIFOETKYgMp7ElQ5anGynFLpTI5NaFRD8IQiMrcCpVDy1L55B6bJEvN6CYSiY5Akggy7XW73BFPZGC5kir4-P4Ak5nYgSsHS6FClnSMhlASdLxk5W2Aj2DzeGr1OCPQLYZjmZbVG2IO2RRE4ZgAJgs5iAA)